# Several invokes to GUI from one thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invoke-sqlcmd

If I run several Invokes from a thread, does it run one after each other?

For example, I have a ListView control and after getting the actual information from a server, I need to clear the items, update group names, add new items, etc. All this requires many call to GUI. Is it sure it will be executed in the called sequence?

Comment: The calls are invoked onto the single UI thread. It does not matter how many threads you call invoke from the single UI thread can only execute one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `Control.Invoke` and `Control.BeginInvoke` guarantee the execution order if called from the same thread.

`Control.Invoke` is synchrnous, so you will not able to call next `Invoke` before the current one will finish.

`Control.BeginInvoke` uses windows messages under the hood and windows messages are prcessed in order in the message loop, so this also will be executed in the same order as it was called.